# Disable f4 key for Launchpad

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, launchpad

I would like to reassign my F4 button on my mac magic keyboard to something else. Unfortunately, when I try to reassign it, it opens Launch Pad.

Here's my keyboard Shortcuts panel... [image]

I'm able to remove the default action for other keys like the F3 key, but not for this one...
How do I remove this default action so I can setup a new use for that F4 key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that F4 is set as Launchpad, it's that you have your F-Keys set as 'special function' keys & that special function happens to be Launchpad. (The set of little squares printed on the key next to F4 - each of those icons represent the special functions)

[image]

If you look at the first tab of that pref pane - Keyboard - You'll see that box is unchecked…

[image]

Once you do that, your 'real' F-Key will come into play, with whatever you set it for in the Shortcuts pane.

Alternatively, you can temporarily swap special function/F-Keys by holding  <kbd>Fn</kbd>

Comment: Yes, you're right. That box is unchecked because I'm currently using other Function keys for different purposes without needing the Fn modifier.  I would like to keep that box unchecked if possible, and remap the F4 key (launchpad key) to use for other stuff.

Comment: You can't remap it, because it's not an F-Key if you have that checkbox the other way. Fn/F swaps how the Mac reads the key.

Comment: Hmm… I found this - [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/) - no idea if it still works in latest macOS. Or maybe  [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) could do it

Comment: Thank you! I looked into my Karabiner settings and saw that Karabiner was actually the problem because it was assigned to Launchpad. I changed that setting to F4 and now it all works. What do I do with this StackExchange post now that I know it was a stupid question?!

Comment: Leave it. It may help someone else in future… part of a global searchable resource :)

Comment: @ScotNery that was it! Finally got rid of F3 and F4 from Karabiner
Thank you!